# Display repeater data horizontally

Tags: c#, asp.net

In continuation to my last question, I was suggested to use Repeater for displaying data fetched from SQL Db in horizontal layout.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25447351/asp-net-c-sharp-customized-gridview/25458682#25458682

As per suggestion I implemented a repeater control. The data was displayed in horizontal layout but only second column fetched from the DB.

How to get the first column too:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server">


   <HeaderTemplate>
         <asp:Literal ID="litRowStart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblExpID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Exp_ID") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
            </td>
            <asp:Literal ID="litRowEnd" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
      </HeaderTemplate>


        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Literal ID="litRowStart1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <td>
                <asp:Label ID="lblExpAmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Amt_Allocated") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
            </td>
            <asp:Literal ID="litRowEnd1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: only second column fetch means?  Its fetching only "Amt_Allocated" but not the "Exp_ID" ????

Comment: I just checked it is fetching both cols, but it is not displaying Exp_ID in Header template

Comment: can you show your sql query ? I mean how you are binding your Repeater Control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create your repeater like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>

        <asp:Repeater ID="repTest" runat="server">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <td>
                    <div>
                        <b>
                            <%#Eval("NameofColumnYOuWantToShowAsHeader") %>
                        </b>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <%#Eval("YourColumnValue") %>
                    </div>
                </td>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>

    </tr>
</table>
```

For more information about repeater: 
[Repeater Insert, Update, Delete in asp .net](http://www.codingfusion.com/Post/Repeater-Edit-Update-Delete-in-Asp-net-using-Ado)

Comment: I did that and this involved some css tweaking too.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one using AlternateingItemTemplate:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="RepDetails" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
            <td>
                <asp:Literal ID="litRowStart" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
                <asp:Label ID="lblExpID" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Exp_ID") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
            <asp:Literal ID="litRowEnd" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            </td>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <AlternatingItemTemplate>
        <td>
            <asp:Literal ID="litRowStart1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
            <asp:Label ID="lblExpAmt" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("Amt_Allocated") %>' Font-Bold="true" />
        <asp:Literal ID="litRowEnd1" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
        </td>
    </AlternatingItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Assuming that you're getting 2 rows in your datasource.

Comment: unfortunately I have 4 columns in total